# Data type of the columns of the temporary tables getting changed in mysql 5.6 onwards

Tags: mysql

Trying to create a temporary table from a select statement.
But the data types of the columns created in the temporary table in mysql 5.5 is different from the data types created in 5.6 and onward.

```
select version();
set sql_mode='';

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_dataset ( 
amountInINR double(20,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
quantity int(10) NOT NULL, 
useQuantity int(10) NOT NULL,
Code varchar(128) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL, 
isPercentageINR int(1) NOT NULL, 
promoDiscountId bigint(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

insert into test_dataset values(1,2,3,4,5,6);

select * from test_dataset;


CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_dataset_temp_0  engine =memory as select if(count(1)=0,0,amountInINR) amountInINR,quantity,useQuantity,Code,isPercentageINR,promoDiscountId  from test_dataset where amountInINR=0;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE test_dataset_temp_1  engine =memory as select amountInINR,quantity,useQuantity,Code,isPercentageINR,promoDiscountId  from test_dataset where amountInINR=0;
desc test_dataset;
desc test_dataset_temp_0;
desc test_dataset_temp_1;
```

Output :

```
   
version : 5.6.35-1+deb.sury.org~xenial+0.1  
desc test_dataset

Field           Type            Null    Key Default Extra
amountInINR     double(20,2)    NO      0.00     
quantity        int(10)         NO      NULL     
useQuantity     int(10)         NO      NULL     
Code            varchar(128)    NO      NULL     
isPercentageINR int(1)          NO      NULL     
promoDiscountId bigint(20)      NO      0    

6 rows (0.002 s) Edit, Export

desc test_dataset_temp_0

Field           Type            Null    Key Default Extra
amountInINR     double(20,2)    YES     NULL     
quantity        bigint(11)      YES     NULL     
useQuantity     bigint(11)      YES     NULL     
Code            varchar(128)    YES     NULL     
isPercentageINR bigint(11)      YES     NULL     
promoDiscountId bigint(20)      YES     NULL     

6 rows (0.002 s) Edit, Export

desc test_dataset_temp_1

Field           Type            Null    Key Default Extra
amountInINR     double(20,2)    NO      0.00     
quantity        int(10)         NO      NULL     
useQuantity     int(10)         NO      NULL     
Code            varchar(128)    NO      NULL     
isPercentageINR int(1)          NO      NULL     
promoDiscountId bigint(20)      NO      0    


version :  5.5.44-log

desc test_dataset

Field           Type            Null    Key Default Extra
amountInINR     double(20,2)    NO      0.00     
quantity        int(10)         NO      NULL     
useQuantity     int(10)         NO      NULL     
Code            varchar(128)    NO      NULL     
isPercentageINR int(1)          NO      NULL     
promoDiscountId bigint(20)      NO      0    

6 rows (0.001 s) Edit, Export

desc test_dataset_temp_0

Field           Type            Null    Key Default Extra
amountInINR     double(20,2)    NO      0.00     
quantity        int(10)         NO      NULL     
useQuantity     int(10)         NO      NULL     
Code            varchar(128)    NO      NULL     
isPercentageINR int(1)          NO      NULL     
promoDiscountId bigint(20)      NO      0    

6 rows (0.001 s) Edit, Export

desc test_dataset_temp_1

Field           Type            Null    Key Default Extra
amountInINR     double(20,2)    NO      0.00     
quantity        int(10)         NO      NULL     
useQuantity     int(10)         NO      NULL     
Code            varchar(128)    NO      NULL     
isPercentageINR int(1)          NO      NULL     
promoDiscountId bigint(20)      NO      0
```

Comment: So what exactly is your question ?

Comment: Why is the datatype of the temporary table getting changed? the datatype created in mysql 5.5 is different from 5.6

Comment: Can anyone help me with this please